# Approximation scheme for potentials in Schrodinger Equation- A Request

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, physics, mathematical-physics

Setup: The Time Independent Schrodinger Equation(Eigenvalue problem):

$(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\Delta +V)\psi = E\psi$

When dealing with computing bound states/bound state energies of say an electron in complicated potentials, one trick I have seen informally is that we can replace the given complicated potential with something that has 'similar behaviour' but has known eigenstates/eigenvalues to 'estimate' the eigenstates/eigenvalues. What I wish to know is, under what conditions is something like this scheme faithful/what conditions need to be imposed to achieve this kind of approximation? Roughly speaking,
If $V$ is the given potential, and $V_{\epsilon}$ is another potential whose eigenvalues and eigenstates are known, such that $\|V_\epsilon-V\|<\epsilon$(in some norm) then if $E_{\epsilon}, E$ denote the ground state energies in $V_{\epsilon}, V$ respectively, then what is an estimate on $|E_{\epsilon}-E|$? Is it of the order $\epsilon$?

I do not know what this class of problems is called so I could not look for it by just googling for example. Any references on it are requested.

Comment: You can get proper double norm bars by using `\|` instead of '||'.

Comment: This is an interesting question: I suggest making the title a bit more informative so that people do not dismiss it (as I nearly did)

Comment: The question has been crossposted here: https://mathoverflow.net/q/442979/492959